# Unitary conserving Schrödinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence, quantum-mechanics, weak-lp-spaces

If we work in the spaces of $N\times N$ matrices we can write the propagator Schrödinger equation as:
$$ \dot{U}(t)=-iH(t)U(t) $$
For some time-dependent Hermitian Hamiltonian $H(t)$. If we assume that this Hamiltonian is bounded in the supremum norm and we can prove existence of a solution for $U$ by considering the integral equation
$$ U(t)=U(0)-i\int_{0}^tH(s)U(s)ds$$. And showing that the the operator
$$ (TU)(t):=U(0)-i\int_{0}^tH(s)U(s)ds$$ is a contraction in the following norm
$$ \|U\|=\sup_{t\in[0,T]}(\|U(t)\|_Fe^{-\lambda t})$$
for small enough $\lambda$. Now I am stuck showing that this also leads to a unitary solution for $U(t)$ as long as $U(0)$ is unitary. Any help would be welcome! I am trying to circumvent the use of the Dyson series, unless it is somehow possible to couple the solution for U(t) found by the contraction to the Dyson series

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use any advanced techniques here - just use that your matrix $H(t)$ is hermitian for all times. Furthermore, you have
$$
(-iH(t)U(t))^{\dagger}=+iU^{\dagger}(t)H(t)
$$
Then we can use the Schroedinger equation to deduce that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}U^{\dagger}(t)U(t)=(\frac{d}{dt}U^{\dagger}(t))U(t)+U^{\dagger}(t)\frac{d}{dt}U(t)=(+iU^{\dagger}(t)H(t))U(t)+U^{\dagger}(t)(-iH(t)U(t))=\pm i U^{\dagger}(t)H(t)U(t)=0
$$
You can do the same calculation for $\frac{d}{dt}UU^{\dagger}$. The you can use that $U(0)U^{\dagger}(0)=1$ and conclude that your matrix is unitary for all times, since the product $U(t)U^{\dagger}(t)$ is constant in time.